# What public-key encryption protocol can use the same key pair as ECDSA?

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, dsa

Assume we wanted to use the same ECDSA public/private key pair (drawn for standard ECC parameters, perhaps [P-256](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf#page=100)) for both its intended use (public-key signature), and for public-key encryption; this despite the sound and explicit prohibition in [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf#page=37):

> ECDSA keys **shall** only be used for the generation and verification of ECDSA digital signatures.

Do we have an option with an argument that (implementation side channels set aside) it does not jeopardize security of ECDSA, and the encryption is safe under CPA?

Can we achieve this with access to the private key for decryption

- strictly limited to ECDSA signing (preferred)
- or is it required a more low-level access to the private key?

Note: I'm meaning ECDSA, if at all possible complete with generation of a true random secret at each signature, no mater how superior Schnorr or/and de-randomized signature is (as used in EdDSA).

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage: I'm ignorant about [VRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_random_function); had to search that! But I'm a tad pessimistic given that I want to use a standard curve (added that requirement).

Comment: On reflection it seems unlikely that an adversary can do much from learning $H([n]P)$ for attacker-chosen points $P$, where $n$ is the secret signing key and $H$ is an _independent_ random oracle from whatever one you use in your ECDSA signature scheme.

Comment: If your encryption provides an ECDH oracle in some way, then security of your private key is diminuished. I remember only darkly but it was by a generic group argument and the security strength will be reduced by a factor of 1/3.

Comment: @Cryptostase Is that when you provide a $P \mapsto [n]P$ oracle, or a $P \mapsto H([n]P)$ oracle?

Comment: There may be a simple answer in this reference which I don't have time to study at the moment: [Jean Paul Degabriele, Anja Lehmann, Kenneth G. Paterson, Nigel P. Smart, and Mario Strefler, ‘On the Joint Security of Encryption and Signature in EMV’, IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive: Report 2011/615, full version of paper presented at CT-RSA 2012.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/615)

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage: I do not know how definitive that is, but at least this reference is 100% spot-on!

Comment: @RSA-129-challenge: As said,I only remember darkly, but I thinkt it is the $P \mapsto n P$ oracle.

Comment: The answer might be complicated by the fact that the security of (EC)DSA itself was [poorly understood for a loooong time](https://sci-hub.tw/https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2978413), unlike Schnorr.